# PDO fetch without moving internal cursor

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I have a method called `getField` and it calls `fetch`, and I was wondering if there is method similar to `fetch`, only that it doesn't move the internal cursor forward, and instead stays where it is.

So, I have the following methods:

```
public function getField($field_name){
    if(!is_array($this->row) || empty($this->row)){
        $this->row = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    return $this->row[$field_name];
}

public function nextRow($type = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    if(!($this->stmt instanceof PDOStatement)){
        return array();
    }
    $this->row = $this->stmt->fetch($type);
    $this->setArray($this->row);
    return $this->row;
}
```

When I call `getFields` then `nextRow` the cursor moves ahead before `nextRow` is called. When that happens I would like the cursor to stay where it is and only increment when `nextRow` is called. Is there something like this?

**Example**

```
$this->db->query($somequery, $arrary_replacements);
if($this->db->getField("myField") === null){
    // Do some stuff
    // Do some database queries too
}else{
    $row = $this->db->nextRow();
    // Process $row
}
```

Comment: Post an example usage.  From what I see, the script should work fine unless `$this->setArray()` is doing something.

Comment: I have made some edits. I understand that I could move the `$row =...` line above the if, but then it isn't with the code that it is used with, and that feels un-organized (to me)

Comment: Why would you even call `nextRow()` there?  It seems unnecessary to me.  You already retrieved the first row when you ran `$this->db->getField("myField")`.  So by the logic of your script, calling nextRow below that is calling for the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your example**

```
$this->db->query($somequery, $arrary_replacements);
if($this->db->getField("myField") === null){
    // Do some stuff
    // Do some database queries too
}else{
    $row = $this->db->nextRow();
    // Process $row
}
```

In my mind, your example usage is flawed.  You have already accessed the first row by using `getField()`, therefore logically, I would assume `nextRow()` should get the second row.  Otherwise you are saying that nextRow should return the current row but continue to the next row, which through my eyes, is confusing.

If you actually want the `$row` for processing then why don't you do this?

```
$this->db->query($somequery, $arrary_replacements);
$row = $this->db->nextRow();
if($row['myField'] === null){
    // Do some stuff
    // Do some database queries too
}else{
    // Process $row
}
```

Otherwise, I think you should consider adding a new function named `getRow()` or `currentRow()` to obtain the current row data (return $this->row) as to not confuse other developers.

Comment: In my example, that is how it was done using the old `mysql` library, so I tried to keep it the same. I didn't create it I am just updating to PDO.